How to type hint a parameter that can be either a list or a single value?
I'm trying to include a type hint to indicate that a parameter can be a list or a single value.
In the code below, I do this using Union. However, is there a better practice?
from typing import Union, Dict, Optional, List

def my_method(self, ex_pararm: Union[List[Union[str, int, float]], str, int, float]):
    pass


You could shorten it by naming Union[str, int, float], but otherwise: that's how you do it. "Better" how?

Do you need specifically list and specifically str | int | float (note that int is a subtype of float for static checkers)? At least you can extract Union[str, float] into a type alias, but likely also replace List with Sequence if you don't need mutability. This is impossible to answer without explanation of what my_method should do and its stub implementation, ideally. This may also be XY.

If you are using Python 3.11+ you should use | rather than Union and | None instead of typing.Optional and directly utilize dict and list or even better code to abtractions provided in collecitons.abc e.g., Mapping, Sequence, MutableMapping etc.

Thanks @jonrsharpe. That makes sense. I was unsure if I was following standard practice or complicating things.

With current versions of Python (3.11+) you don't need the typing module to annotate unions or lists, and can do:
def my_method(self, ex_param: list[str | float] | str | float):
    pass

Note that you can always pass an int where a float is expected, so int | float is unnecessary.
In some situations you might want to define an alias for a pattern that you'll repeat, in this case str | float:
MyScalar = str | float

def my_method(self, ex_param: list[MyScalar] | MyScalar):
    pass

The main benefit of using an alias like this is readability, i.e. being able to assign a meaningful/shorter name to that union type to make it easier to recognize visually than it would be if it were typed out each time, so I'd only do this if the context is such that you can actually come up with a meaningful name.

I believe in 3.12 you can parametrise functions and so express the bounds inline eg. def myfunc[T: str | float](ex_param: list[T] | T): pass -- a single list may contain both strings and floats. Or you can use [T: (str, float)], to say you may pass a list that contains only strings or only floats.

@Dunes no, that's not what this syntax does. def myfunc[T: str|float](x: T) is equivalent to T = TypeVar('T', bound=str|float); def myfync(x: T). It does not relate to defining type aliases.

Generic functions do let you express things that type aliases can't, but that only really kicks in when the return type is related to the arg type.
